# Подключить интерфейс

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Ниже код.Вот что делает: В открытом окне клик по кнопке старт и прога начинает стучаться по урлам проверяя их доступность. Если получает 200 все ок, если нет, то пишет в окне, что такой то сервис недоступен и идет дальше. Сейчас при прохождении урла, он переписывает заголовок. А надо чтоб в тело писал. и не много логика тут не так. Прошу помоч по условию. Желательно пример кода. Спасибо

```
  from tkinter import *
import requests


def clicked():
    lbl.configure(text='мониторинг запущен')
    urls = ['url', 'url', 'url']
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        i = r.status_code
        if i != 200:
            lbl.config(text=url+"бла-бла-бла")
        else:
            lbl.configure(text=url + "бла")

def click():
    lbl.configure(text='мониторинг остановлен')

def click_sibel():
    lbl.configure(text='Sibel not found')


window = Tk()
window.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение")
window.geometry('400x250')
lbl = Label(window, text="Мониторинг систем")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
btn = Button(window, text='Старт', command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=1)
btn = Button(window, text='Стоп', command=click)
btn.grid(column=1, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот работающий у меня ответ. Может кому пригодится:

```
from tkinter import *
import requests


def clicked():
    lbl.configure(text='мониторинг запущен')
    urls = ['url', 'url']
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        i = r.status_code
        if i != 200:
            tx.insert(INSERT, "\n\r" + url + " not found")


def click():
    lbl.configure(text='мониторинг остановлен')

def click_sibel():
    lbl.configure(text='Sibel not found')


window = Tk()
window.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение")
window.geometry('800x640')
lbl = Label(window, text="Мониторинг систем")
tx = Text(window)
tx.grid(column=0, row=2)
tx.insert(INSERT, "hui")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
btn = Button(window, text='Старт', command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=1)
btn = Button(window, text='Стоп', command=click)
btn.grid(column=1, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```